# Connecting over the empty data points

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly

I am trying to plot `trace1` and `trace2`. The problem with `trace1` is that it has missing `y` values for `x = 2` and `x = 3`. The plot that is created looks like the following:

[image]

As could be see the `blue dot` at the left is isolated. Is there a way I could connect over the `undefined` data points?

I created the following code for the above graph.

```
 var trace1 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [10, undefined, undefined, 17, 50],
    type: 'scatter',
};

var trace2 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [16, 5, 11, 9, 40],
    type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

I want to connect y = 10 to y = 17, so that there is no break in the graph

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an attribute named `connectgaps` in both of your objects.

```
var trace1 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    connectgaps: true,
    y: [10, undefined, undefined, 17, 50],
    type: 'scatter',
};

var trace2 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    connectgaps: true,
    y: [16, 5, 11, 9, 40],
    type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

This shall fix it and the new plot would look similar to:

[image]